# Cuidaos, amigos y amigas

Tags: discusión

Esta pregunta no es sobre el sitio, sino sobre algo más importante aún: vosotros.

Imagino que muchos que estáis leyendo lo hacéis confinados en casa debido al coronavirus, pasando las horas como buenamente podéis: con hijos correteando por casa mientras el teletrabajo aprieta, con la angustia de un familiar que no se encuentra bien o está solo, con ganas de salir de casa y airearos...

A todos, muchos ánimos. Nos han tocado días complicados que esperemos que sean breves.

Un abrazo a todos (virtual, por precaución :D) y cuidaos.

Comment: If anyone needs any home activities for children (probably mostly in English, sorry) [click here](https://www.reddit.com/r/boston/comments/fjqsmv/if_anyone_needs_any_home_activities_for_children/). Acababa de publicarlo en los [community adds](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3321/5481) Si encuentro més recursos los traeré a este hilo.

Comment: Tremenda iniciativa, gracias Diego. A mí se me están acabando los recursos :D

Answer (score 3):

Os pongo por aquí algunos consejos que estamos intentando aplicar en casa y que nos van bien:

1. Dado que vamos a tener que estar en casa bastante tiempo, haced una planificación para que la cosa no se vaya de madre. Dividid todas las horas del día desde que los niños se despiertan hasta que se acuestan, y especificad lo que se puede hacer en cada tramo. Comidas, ver películas, juego libre, tareas de clase, videojuegos, etc. Es mejor que los peques sepan a qué atenerse a cada hora del día que tenerlos en la incertidumbre.
2. Aprovechad para poner en marcha algún hobby o ejercicio, si puede ser implicando a los niños mejor. Nosotros hemos empezado a hacer rutinas de ejercicio divertido con los peques todas las tardes. Si no, suscribíos a algún canal de YouTube de divulgación y aprovechad para aprender cosas nuevas.
3. Si el tiempo lo permite salid adonde podáis a respirar aire puro al menos un par de veces al día. Nosotros tenemos la suerte de tener un jardín privado, pequeño pero apañado, en el que poder hacer un poco de vida, pero si no, salid al balcón o asomaos a la ventana o lo que sea.
4. Aunque parezca una tontería, la rutina de salir a aplaudir a las ocho te permite saber que hay mucha gente cerca que está igual que tú, a la vez que te permite hablar con tus vecinos cercanos. No solo muestras apoyo sino que te da fuerzas para seguir adelante.
5. Dividid las salidas entre todos. Si uno sale a tirar la basura, otro que saque al perro y otro que vaya a la compra cuando sea necesario.

Y, por supuesto, mucha paciencia. Iré ampliando la lista si se me ocurren más cosas.

¡Abrazos para todos!